# How to specify radius units in addCircleMarkers() when using Leaflet in R

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm trying to visualize a shipment from origin to destination using a leaflet map created with R within a shiny application.

I want to add a circle marker of a radius corresponding to a the **odist** and **ddist** variables which come form a reactive dataframe called **main()**

below is a relevant snapshot with accompanying code:

[image: Pic1]

```
output$leaflet1 <- renderLeaflet({
  leaflet() %>%
    addCircleMarkers(data = main(), lng = main()$Olong, lat = main()$Olat, color = 'black', fillColor = coyGreen,
                     radius = main()$odist, opacity = .5) %>% 
    addCircleMarkers(data = main(), lng = main()$Dlong, lat = main()$Dlat, color = 'black', fillColor = coyGreen, 
                     radius = main()$ddist, opacity = .3)
})
```

For the above example the argument `radius = main()$odist` is equivalent to `radius = 50`. However, the 50 units seem to be arbitrary (the cirlce is smaller than the larger one with `radius = main()$ddist = 125` however both circles enlarge and shrink as I zoom in and out). I would like to be able to set the radius of my circle marker to be a fixed radius in miles, however I haven't been able to figure out how to do so. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `addCircles` is what you're looking for I think

Comment: I'm looking for a way to set the `radius` argument to a fixed constant in miles.

Comment: In the [online documentation of leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circle) for Circle it says that `setRadius` "Sets the radius of a circle. Units are in meters." So in R leaflet when you use `addCircles` instead of `addCircleMarkers` you can specify the radius in meters (or miles if you convert properly).

Comment: I'm using the leaflet() package for R so I'm not sure that same syntax is applicable. The argument in R is `radius` which from the visual the two circles shown clearly don't have radii of 50 and 125 meters.

Comment: Yes, this is because (at least in the code you show above) you are using `addCircleMarkers` where you should be using `addCircles`

Comment: I tried both, I still don't think that's the correct syntax. `Error: unused agrument (setRadius = main()$ddist)`

Comment: The argument is, as you state above, called `radius = ` in R leaflet. When used in `addCircles` this defines the radius of the circles in meters.

Comment: @TimSalabim using `addCircles()` was able to give my desired output, thank you! If you'd like to post an answer I'd be happy to accept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use `addCircles` instead of `addCircleMarkers` your circles will have constant `radius` (in meters). Here's a reproducible example using **mapview** which uses `addCircleMarkers`. On top we plot the same locations using `addCircles`

```
library(mapview)

m <- mapview(breweries91) # uses addCirclemarkers so circle radius changes with zoom

m@map %>% 
  addCircles(data = breweries91, color = "red", radius = 100) # circle radius constant
```

If you zoom in you will see that the initially smaller red circles will become bigger in relation to the standard blue circlemarkers used in **mapview**

Comment: I am trying to use the ```addCircles``` but i get the error "Don't know how to get location data from object of class sfc_MULTIPOLYGON,sfc"

Answer (score 0):

It is important to remember the map projections.

It also depends on the projection you are using in Leaflet, it is good to check it with Leaflet's measurement tools or if you know the location well. To see the projections I recommend

```
crsDF <- rgdal::make_EPSG()
View(crsDF)
```

In my case, that I am in Chile (a long and narrow country) I use this projection for some places:

CRS 9155 =

```
"+proj=utm +zone=19 +south +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs"
```

There you can see that I am using units in meters

Here I leave an image of some projections for my country.

```
View(crsDF)
```

[image: View(crsDF)]

You can find more in:

- https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/spatial-class.html#projected-coordinate-reference-systems
- https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/spatial-class.html#crs-in-r

Greetings